# Show that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $f(0)\ge 0$. Suppose $f'(x)\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in(0, \infty)$. Show that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0, \infty)$.

**Proof**

Denote $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x),(x \geq 0)$. For any $x>0$ , we have $g'(x)=e^{-x}[f'(x)-f(x)]\geq 0$. Hence, $g(x)$ is increasing over $[0,+\infty)$. Thus, $e^{-x}f(x)=g(x) \geq g(0)=f(0) \geq 0.$ As a result, $f(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: Is there a question hiding in here somewhere?

Comment: This is clever.  And it works.  But you are doing yourself a *huge* disservice by not doing it the "real" way.  It's bit like coming up with some cheating method to doing fractions because fractions are too hard and then two years later discovering you simply don't understand fractions at all but it's too late as you already passed basic arithmetic.  This will bite you eventually.  Um,  do you see the "real" way you were *supposed* to do it?

Comment: @mengdie fleablood's comment hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @fleablood I rack my brains to understand you,but I get nothing. Can you just talk about mathematics rather than those, frankly speaking, nonsense?

Comment: @fleablood I say $g(x)$ is increasing, that's because $g'(x) \geq 0$, which is from the condition $f'(x)-f(x) \geq 0$. Can you understand this?

Comment: What?  I understood your proof perfectly.  And it's correct and clever.  And you'd be a prime contender for my "shining star/nightmare" student.  But you are doing a complicated avoidence of basic definitions and continuity theorems (mean, intermediate) which will cause problems later.

Comment: @fleablood Sir, I indeed  used some trick method to solve the problem,but it was also perfectly rigorous. You mean that I should aviod that? If you have a proof to deal with it directly without introducing any auxiliary function, I'm glad to see that.